# Rails help counting rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a problem counting my rows in Konkurrancers table.

I have tried this, but it dos not work it render the page but it dont display the number of konkurrancers.

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  require 'dynamic_form' 
@konkurrencerall = Konkurrancer.find(:all).count
end
```

My layout file:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Konkurranceportalen</title>
      </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Velkommen til Konkurranceportalen er kan du vælge imellem <span class="nummer"><%= @konkurrencerall %></span> <b>gratis</b> konkurrancer! </h1>
<%= yield %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to run any logic that should execute every request into a `before_filter`:

```
require 'dynamic_form'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :count_kunkurrancers

  def count_kunkurrancers
    @konkurrencerall = Konkurrancer.count
  end
end
```

Comment: I know it is another question. But how do I count the Konkurrancers in a given category? I have tried something like this @konkurrencerall = Konkurrancer.where(:name == params[:id]).count

Comment: Like this: `@konkurrencerall = Konkurrancer.where("name = ?", params[:id]).count`. Note the use of `?`: it is **very important** in order to avoid [SQL Injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: The "where" clause takes a Hash, should be: where(:name => value)

Comment: Both answers are correct. If you are performing an equality check, then the form `where(:column => value` is typically used; but `where` can also do other checks, like `where("date < ?", Time.now)`